# jQuery method to click on image/caption or <li> to go to URL

Tags: jquery

I'd like to use an image slider plugin (Elastislide) as a menu. The problem is that it uses `<a href="#">` as a function and can't be used as a link. I've tried. So, I'm looking for a jQuery solution to use the images/captions or a `<li>` as a pseudo-link.

The pages are all local, so I don't need to go to another domain, just another page in the same directory. Here's an example of the HTML

```
        <div id="carousel" class="es-carousel-wrapper">

        <div class="es-carousel">

        <ul>

    <li value="another_page.php"><a href="#"><img src="images/small/1.jpg" alt="image01" /></a></li>
    <li value="yet_another.php"><a href="#"><img src="images/small/2.jpg" alt="image02" /></a></li>
    <li value="still_another.php"><a href="#"><img src="images/small/3.jpg" alt="image03" /></a></li>
    <li value="last_one.php"><a href="#"><img src="images/small/4.jpg" alt="image04" /></a></li>

</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

I added the value getting a clue from another post.

Comment: what do you mean by 'it uses `<a href='#'>` as a function'?

Comment: you try to use window.location

Comment: I'm only assuming that it uses it to manipulate the slider itself because it doesn't respond to it as a link. I can see the URL at the bottom of the browser window, but it doesn't go to it when I click it.

Comment: Is it possible to create a working example, perhaps on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: just wondering if my answer was useful at all or if there's more i could help ya with?

Comment: @SpYk3HH - Actually, it seems like the code is not even being addressed. I mean that I added an alert after the plugin initialize and got the alert box, then I added it after your code and nothing. I'm going to throw it up on jsFiddle.

Comment: @SpYk3HH - Added it to jsFiddle, (see above) in case you didn't know... And thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can add a class to each `li`, you could easily reference that class and do something like:

```
$(".li-class").on("click", function(e) {
    $("#IDofSomeLoadAreaDiv").empty().load($(this).attr("value"));
});
```

Tho you might need to change the link in those value's to represent the whole link and not just a partial

Also, if you added something like [myURL Extension](http://spyk3lc.blogspot.com/2012/03/jquery-myurl-extension-how-to-get-that.html), you could do something like:

```
$(".li-class").on("click" function(e) {
    $("#IDofSomeLoadAreaDiv").empty().load($.myURL("index", $(this).attr("value")));
});
// and this would eliminate the need to assure correct full link in each li, 
// as it would call your base site url, add index.php to it and then add 
// the link in your li.value
```

It appears I may have misread the question, if you're not looking to load the view partial into the current page.  In other words, if you want to "refresh" the page with the new link, do the following:

```
$(".li-class").on("click", function(e) {
    window.location = $(this).attr("value");
});
// or with myURL extension if you want
$(".li-class").on("click" function(e) {
    window.location = $.myURL("index", $(this).attr("value"));
});
```

ALSO! If you want to open it in a new window, I also have a simple jQuery Extension for that ([see jsFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/9NS5K/), copy the js code between the long commented lines) that can make it as easy as:

```
$(".li-class").on("click" function(e) {
    $.winOpen($.myURL("index", $(this).attr("value")), "windowName", { fullscreen: "no", height: "600px", toolbar: 1, width: 600 });
});
```

> BIG UPDATE: The fiddle helped, helped to know you where using an older jQuery

With that version of jQuery you don't have .on, you also where trying to use the myURL plugin without actually adding the plugin.
I've recreated working version of your fiddle [***HERE***](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/HsD2D/)

IF you want to use that plugin, you'll either need to add it to your header or create a js file for it and link it in your header like any other jquery plugin, if not, you can just create the links directly as shown in previous examples.

> More UPDATE: Found issue where that ver of jQuery won't support just any attr (aka "value") from an element.  Changed `<li value="` to `<li href="` and crrected it in the javascript call as well.

Also, to make that location call without the myURL plugin you could simply replace:

```
window.location = $.myURL("index", $(this).attr("value"));
```

with

```
window.location = $(this).attr("value");
```

But, remember, that means making sure you have the FULL site url on each li's href attr

Comment: Don't forget the comma after "click"

Comment: @SpYk3HH - What is the reason for the `#IDofSomeLoadAreaDiv`, or specifically, what particular value would go there?

Comment: Well, if i read your quest right, you don't wanna reload or go to new page, but rather load the new view partial into current page.  The `$("#IDofSomeLoadAreaDiv")` is reference to a div on your page where you want the new view partial to load

Comment: @SpYk3HH - I actually do want it to go to a different page, not to load a different `<div>`. So, when you click on the `<li>` it goes to the page represented in the value. Read the second paragraph in my Q.

Comment: Changed answer to refelct both possibilities, loading new view in current page, and loading it into an Element in the current page

Comment: Made another update to answer in case you want "new window" flexability

Comment: @SpYk3HH - if it matters, I got `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'` in the error log.

Comment: NP, see "BIG UPDATE" in my answer

Comment: lol, found another issue, that ver of jquery wont support "value" attr recall on li's, try changing it to somthing like href, gonna edit my fiddle now

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10293/discussion-between-adam-and-spyk3hh)